# Why is putenv() needed on an already defined environment variable?

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, environment-variables

When `php` is used as an `apache` module, an environment variable coming from an apache `SetEnv` directive is available to php's `getenv()`, but it does not appear to be available to `C` extensions through stdlib's `getenv()`. At least it happens with the `pgsql` module.

If the variable is reinstantiated with the php code:

```
putenv("varname=".getenv("varname"));
```

then it becomes available to the extension's code.

The question: why is that reinstantiation necessary? How is the core php environment distinct from the "standard" (`stdlib`) environment?

This occurs with: `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.17` in Ubuntu 12.04, as an apache module. When run from the command line, the above workaround is not necessary.
From this other question: [Using .pgpass from Apache libphp5.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677674) it appears that this workaround is also necessary for php-5.4 under FreeBSD so it's not just Ubuntu or php-5.3.

It doesn't depend on `variables_order` having `E` in it. I've tried both `EGPCS` and `GPCS`, and `$_ENV` is not populated when `E` is not there, as expected, but that doesn't change the result of `getenv()`, as [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), or apparently the result of stdlib's `getenv()` from inside extensions.

---

**Demo of the problem** with the `pgsql` module. It's built on top of the   `libpq` shared library written in `C`, which calls `getenv()` on a handful of optional `PG*` environment variables.

In apache configuration file, under a `<VirtualHost>`, I'm setting this to make connection attempts fail:

```
SetEnv PGHOST doesnotexist
```

and not specifying a host in the `pg_connect` call, so `PGHOST` must be taken when present.

**First try**:

```
$v=getenv("PGHOST");
echo "PGHOST=$v\n";

$cnx=pg_connect("user=daniel");
if ($cnx) {
   echo "Connection is successful.";
}
```

Result:

```
PGHOST=doesnotexist
Connection is successful.
```

So `PGHOST` is getting ignored, despite being in the environment.

**Second try**, now putting again `PGHOST` into the environment even though it's already there:

```
$v=getenv("PGHOST");
echo "PGHOST=$v\n";
putenv("PGHOST=".getenv("PGHOST"));
$cnx=pg_connect("user=daniel");
if ($cnx) {
   echo "Connection is successful.";
}
```

Result (failure to connect to the specified host, as expected):

```
PGHOST=doesnotexist
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server:
could not translate host name "doesnotexist" to address:
Name or service not known in /var/www/test/pgtest2.php on line 8
```

Comment: I see you have unix paths, but do you happen to be on something like cygwin? There is a windows issue in this neighborhood based on which C runtimes different shared libs are linked against.

Comment: No this happens with linux ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Also happens on FreeBSD 10.1 with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Interesting thing that I have noticed is that environment variables defined in Apache's `envvars` configuration file are available to extensions.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is this:

The environment values you get from `getenv()[PHP]` (the php function) are different than the environment you query with `getenv()[C]` (the C lib function). What `getenv()[PHP]` does, is checking with the registered sapi for a match (http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#3999).

The apache2 sapi does this through its own environment context (http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#253), not the standard OS environment from the apache process itself.

ONLY when there is no match found, it will check at the environment of the actual process. So this is why `getenv()[PHP]` returns a value, but `getenv()[C]` does not.

Now, the "hack" is a simple one as well: `putenv()[PHP]`, stores the given key/value in the environment of the running process, which is why it can be found later on by `getenv()[c]`.